# Weak incidence colouring

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring

Let $G(V,E)$ be a simple undirected graph, let $k\in \mathbb{N}$, and let $I(G)=\{(v,e)\ :\ e\in E, v\in e \}$ (here, $v\in e$ means $v$ is incident on $e$). A $k$-incidence colouring of $G$ is a function $c:I(G)\to \{1,2,\dots,k\}$ such that the following hold for all $u,v\in V$ and $e,f\in E$ :
(i) $c(\,(v,e)\,)\neq c(\,(v,f)\,)$,
(ii) $c(\,(u,e)\,)\neq c(\,(v,e)\,)$, and
(iii) if $e=\{u,v\}$, then $c(\,(u,e)\,)\neq c(\,(v,f)\,)$.

I am interested in the weak variant where we drop condition (iii). Let us call it weak incidence colouring. That is, a $k$-weak incidence colouring of $G$ is a function $c:I(G)\to \{1,2,\dots,k\}$ such that $c(\,(v,e)\,)\neq c(\,(v,f)\,)$,  and $c(\,(u,e)\,)\neq c(\,(v,e)\,)$ for all $u,v\in V$ and $e,f\in E$. This seems to be a very natural relaxation to me.
**I couldn't find any paper that study weak incidence colouring.

Is this because this is equivalent to some known notion?**
We know that incidence colouring has several equivalent characterizations, for instance, in terms of strong edge colouring (or directed star arboricity). See "Links with other notions" in [The Incidence Coloring Page](https://www.labri.fr/perso/sopena/pmwiki/index.php?n=TheIncidenceColoringPage.TheIncidenceColoringPage) maintained by Éric Sopena.

If it matters, I am particularly interested in the complexity of $k$-weak incidence colouring of $k$-regular graphs. Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this problem has another name, but it seems like it's easy to solve.

We first see that a weak incidence coloring of a graph $G$ corresponds to an edge coloring of the graph $G'$ obtained by subdividing each edge of $G$ once. This, in turn, corresponds to a vertex coloring of $L(G')$, the line graph of $G'$. This line graph consists of a collection of cliques, one for each vertex in the original graph $G$. Each vertex in each clique is adjacent to one and only one vertex in another clique.

Now, it is not hard to prove that $L(G')$ is a perfect graph by the strong perfect graph theorem (neither $L(G')$ or $\overline{L(G')}$ have any long odd cycles). This implies that the chromatic number of $L(G')$ is equal to the size of the largest clique in $L(G')$, which in turn implies that the weak incidence coloring number of $G$ is equal to $\Delta(G)$.